# How to show each label in a row or column

Tags: python, kivy

In the code below I have a second screen, and I tried to add two buttons to this screen, but one button is on top of the other, I can see it when I use label instead.

I need to add each Label on a row or column because at the moment I cant even read the Label text.

This is how I add the label to new screen:

```
self.new_screen.add_widget(Label(text='LABEL NUMER 1'))
self.new_screen.add_widget(Label(text='THIS IS THE LABEL NUMBER 2'))
```

full code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows= 3

        self.titlet = Label(text='MAIN SCREEN')
        self.add_widget(self.titlet)

        self.MainGrid = GridLayout()
        self.MainGrid.cols = 2

        self.b4 = Button(text="Botao")
        self.MainGrid.add_widget(self.b4)

        self.add_widget(self.MainGrid)


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.main_screen = Screen(name="main_screen")
        self.new_screen = Screen(name="new_screen")
        self.add_widget(self.main_screen)
        self.add_widget(self.new_screen)

        self.grid = Grid()
        self.grid.b4.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)

        self.new_screen.cols = 2

        self.new_screen.add_widget(Label(text='LABEL NUMER 1'))
        self.new_screen.add_widget(Label(text='THIS IS THE LABEL NUMBER 2'))

        self.main_screen
        self.main_screen.add_widget(self.grid)

    def change_screen(self, *args):
        self.current = "new_screen"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you have established a layout on the first Screen you must do it with the second Screen, in this case you must use BoxLayout:

```py
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

# ...

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.main_screen = Screen(name="main_screen")
        self.new_screen = Screen(name="new_screen")
        self.add_widget(self.main_screen)
        self.add_widget(self.new_screen)

        self.grid = Grid()
        self.grid.b4.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)

        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.new_screen.add_widget(box_layout)

        box_layout.add_widget(Label(text='LABEL NUMER 1'))
        box_layout.add_widget(Label(text='THIS IS THE LABEL NUMBER 2'))

        self.main_screen.add_widget(self.grid)

    # ...
```

Comment: thanks, worked again. but why i cant use GridLayout? and, what if i need create another screen, ill need to use other grid manager?

Comment: @LuanGabriel Who has indicated that you cannot use a GridLayout ?, You can use it but for me it is more correct to use BoxLayout since you require the design of a row or column, a GridLayout instead is for a grid structure. I recommend you take some basic kivy course, or at least read the tutorials that kivy offers so that you understand how it works. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/